# enable paging at databound detailsview with data from web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, detailsview

- Am using VS2008 ASP.Net Web Forms
- have a detailsview, databound to web service reference

Currently my web service correctly displays the number of records when invoked. However when bound to the detailsview, i need paging to be enabled in order to display the relevant records. How may i ensure this is done? I have the following code:

```
  Protected Sub DetailsView1_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewPageEventArgs) Handles DetailsView1.PageIndexChanging
        DetailsView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex

        'Am i missing out some codes or steps here?         
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing:

```
DetailsView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: Yes! :) to be specific, it was DetailsView1.DataSource = a.getItemDetails()
            DetailsView1.DataBind()